# Tring to call functions of an unkown WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webassembly

I try to call functions of an unknown-WebAssembly «Or better said, i try to simulate them» and if the functions has a return value to get its return value.

I cant get with following code i cant get exports, but can't get any info which parameters are needed for it.

```
instance.exports();
```

That's why i wrote a parser to find out functions of WebAssembly-File and their parameter. After i got these infos, i tried to call an export function and got following error:

> import object field 'env' is not an Object.

And its header:

```
  (import "env" "DYNAMICTOP_PTR" (global $env.DYNAMICTOP_PTR i32))
  (import "env" "STACKTOP" (global $env.STACKTOP i32))
  (import "env" "STACK_MAX" (global $env.STACK_MAX i32))
  (import "env" "abort" (func $env.abort (type $t1)))
  (import "env" "enlargeMemory" (func $env.enlargeMemory (type $t2)))
  (import "env" "getTotalMemory" (func $env.getTotalMemory (type $t2)))
  (import "env" "abortOnCannotGrowMemory" (func $env.abortOnCannotGrowMemory (type $t2)))
  (import "env" "_gmtime" (func $env._gmtime (type $t3)))
  (import "env" "___setErrNo" (func $env.___setErrNo (type $t1)))
  (import "env" "_emscripten_memcpy_big" (func $env._emscripten_memcpy_big (type $t4)))
  (import "env" "___syscall20" (func $env.___syscall20 (type $t5)))
  (import "env" "_ftime" (func $env._ftime (type $t3)))
  (import "env" "memory" (memory $env.memory 256 256))
  (import "env" "table" (table $env.table 8 8 anyfunc))
  (import "env" "memoryBase" (global $env.memoryBase i32))
  (import "env" "tableBase" (global $env.tableBase i32))
```

The reason is clear: Because i didn't define any import object. i have following idea to solve this:

I define the importObject so that it meets minimum requirements. I found following code for some imports:

```
    table: new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 0, maximum: 0, element: 'anyfunc' }),
    tableBase: 0,
    memory: memory,
    memoryBase: 1024,
    STACKTOP: 0,
    STACK_MAX: memory.buffer.byteLength,
```

But there are too many different imports. I couldn't find a list, which gives me all import types and their definition. That's why w want to create my own table to solve this problem. Could you give me some informations or help me to make this table?

Answer (score 2):

> I couldn't find a list, which gives me all import types and their definition

The reason you couldn't find such a list is because it doesn't exist!

WebAssembly modules can import or export functions (as well as tables, memory, and globals). What you choose to import or export is entirely up to you and depends on what you are trying to achieve with your WebAssembly module. A simple module that just adds two numbers together might export a single `add` function.

From your code samples, it looks like you are using Emscripten, which adds a lot of infrastructure / framework code around your WebAssembly modules. AS this code isn't generally considered part of their API, you might need to delve into the code to determine what the import object looks like:

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/78b44ed55cc4d0b4d79f62df9e80ae6f29a5345b/src/preamble.js